# Scala Spark: Calling Fortran Subroutine in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a subroutine written in Fortran and I would like to call it in Spark (Scala). What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Calling a subroutine in Fortran from Spark boils down to calling native code from Scala or Java.

Have a look at [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) or [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) (JNA is higher level and might be easier to use).

Comment: awesome! I'll take a look at this!